# Remove lines from inside a polygon (shapefile) in r

Tags: polygon, r, sp, ggplot2, ggmap

[image]I have this code which prints the Galápagos Islands. But inside the islands, there are lines that I want to get rid off. How is this possible in R?

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)

URL <- "https://osm2.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?filename=public.galapagos_islands&q=select+*+from+public.galapagos_islands&format=geojson&bounds=&api_key="
fil <- "gal.json"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)
gal <- readOGR(fil, "OGRGeoJSON")    
gal_map <- fortify(gal)
ggplot() + 
  geom_map(map=gal_map, data=gal_map, aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id)) + 
  coord_equal()
```

Look at the picture: I don't want to show these lines (all of them).

Comment: Do you want to 'get rid of' the lines by changing the geometry or just the display?

Comment: I don't want to display the lines inside the islands. I just want the contour and a color to fill the islands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate the polygons and then disaggregate to the 182 individual islands.

```
URL <- "https://osm2.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?filename=public.galapagos_islands&q=select+*+from+public.galapagos_islands&format=geojson&bounds=&api_key="
fil <- "gal.json"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

library(rgdal)
gal <- readOGR(fil, "OGRGeoJSON")   

library(raster)
library(rgeos)

a <- aggregate(gal)
b <- disaggregate(a)

plot(b, col=sample(rainbow(length(b))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the 'lines' you are referring to are simply the polygon boundaries separating one feature from another. If you just want to display the data and you do not necessarily have to stick with `ggplot2`, a possible option would be to use `spplot`. Just create a plot of the non-unified polygons with "transparent" line color (see `?sp.polygons`) and add the island boundary afterwards using `layer` from **latticeExtra**. Note the use of `unionSpatialPolygons` from **maptools** to merge all polygons into one, thus ending up with the coastline only.

```
## add 'id' column
gal@data$id <- seq(gal@data$fid) - 1

## unify polygons
library(maptools)
gal_union <- unionSpatialPolygons(gal, IDs = rep(1, length(gal)))

## display data with island boundaries only
library(latticeExtra)
spplot(gal, "id", col = "transparent", scales = list(draw = TRUE), 
       at = seq(gal@data$id), col.regions = rainbow(nrow(gal@data))) + 
  layer(sp.polygons(gal_union, fill = "transparent"))
```

[image: spplot]

If I got you wrong and you are trying to merge particular polygons e.g. based on their spatial location, I highly recommend having a deeper look at `?unionSpatialPolygons` and, for instance, the related post on [Joining polygons in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63577/joining-polygons-in-r/63696#63696).

---

**Update**:

This would be a possible (yet very basic) **ggplot2** version of the above code (with the legend disabled).

```
gal_ff <- fortify(gal)
gal_union_ff <- fortify(gal_union)

ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id, fill = id), data = gal_ff) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = gal_union_ff, 
            colour = "black") +
  scale_fill_discrete(guide = FALSE) + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: If I want to stay with `ggplot2 ` is there a way to join the polygons?

Comment: Based on which feature property would you like to join the polygons? Or is it just about not displaying the inland polygon borders?

Comment: I just want to remove the lines inside the islands. Later, I'll try to apply a different colour to each island.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil then the above update should fit your needs. Have a particular look at `group = group` inside `geom_path` that is responsible for the grouping of multiple polygons located on the same island.

Comment: Sorry, but I still see some lines. I don't understand what `group = group` or `group = id` is making. Plus, I'm using ggmap. I don't know if it's the issue

Comment: @M.Beausoleil: To understand this answer perhaps it helps you to simplify the suggested code like: `ggplot() +  geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), data = gal_union_ff,  colour = "black") +  coord_equal()`